# how to combine inequalities in proof

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to follow along with a proof in class but there's one step relating to inequalities that I don't quite understand and would like assistance with.

$$a = qb + r = q’b + r’$$
$$0 \leq r, r’ < b$$
$$q,r,q’,r’ \in \mathbb{Z}$$

The aim is to show $q=q’$ and $r=r’$

Rearranging the first equality gives us $(q-q’)b = r’ - r$

$r’-r$ is a multiple of $b$

Since $0 \leq r' < b$, negating gives us $-b < -r \leq 0$

This is the part where I get stuck. The proof jumps straight to the following:

$$-b< r’-r < b$$

Can I please have assistance in understanding how we go from $0 \leq r < b$, and $-b < -r \leq 0$ to the above?

Comment: Note that $0\leq r'<b$.

Comment: add the sides and the middle of the two inequalities together!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $0\leq r' <b$ and $r'-r<r'$, using these two you get that $r'-r < b$.

Similarly, since $-b < -r$ and $-r < r'-r$, you get that $-b < r'-r$.

Using both, 
$$
-b < r'-r < b.
$$